# Template specialization in presence of variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a struct `foo` as so -

```
template <typename T, typename...V>
struct foo;
```

I want to specialize this struct when `T` meets a specific condition, namely when it inherits from a class `bar`.

I know how to write this condition using `std::is_base_of<bar, T>::value` and combine it with `std::enable_if`.

Without the variadic template I could use an extra template argument (`void`) and default argument like so -

```
template <typename T, class Enable=void>
struct foo {
    // default implementation
};

template <typename T>
struct foo <T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<bar, T>::value>::type> {
    // Implementation when T inherits from bar
};
```

But I cannot combine variadic templates and default template argument because both need to be the last template arguments.

Any suggestions how I can implement this specialization?

Comment: But I would use alias instead of inheritance in both the answers.

Comment: @Quimby I see, that makes sense, explicitly using an enable_if with negated condition instead of default template argument should do the trick. I have closed the question.

Comment: Worth noting that using C++20 concepts makes this really easy, if that option is available to you: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95b14d15c93bcd4a

Comment: @N.Shead I am trying to keep the code base for the project restricted to c++11 as much as possible. But thanks for the pointer to the concepts based solution. Added to the arsenal.